# Laravel WooCommerce - Using the DB Facade to insert into categories

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having issues with creating WooCommerce product_cats using laravel. I am creating the process of a large feed and using laravel for it. I could use laravel corcel, but it doesn't have all the facilities that I need.

I need to have parent child relationships, to be able to attach the categories and see them in the WordPress admin.

The code is creating the categories, but they are not attaching to the products, and not viewable/manipulatable within the wordpress admin area.

```
 private function addSections($sections) {
            Log::info("Sections:", $sections);

            $cat_ids = [];

            $category_hierarchy = [
                'Categories',
                'Product Sub-Group',
                'Product Group',
                'Product Sub-Group 1',
                'Product Type'
            ];

            $connection = DB::connection('wordpress');

            foreach ($category_hierarchy as $category) {
                if (isset($sections[$category]) && !$this->skipCategory($sections[$category])) {

                    // Check if the term already exists
                    $term = $connection->table('terms')
                        ->where('name', $sections[$category])
                        ->first();

                    if (!$term) {
                        $term_id = $connection->table('terms')->insertGetId([
                            'name' => $sections[$category],
                            'slug' => Str::slug($sections[$category])
                        ]);

                        // Insert into the term_taxonomy table
                        $connection->table('term_taxonomy')->insert([
                            'term_id' => $term_id,
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'parent' => $parent_id,
                        ]);
                    } else {
                        $term_id = $term->term_id;
                    }

                    $parent_id = $term_id;
                    $cat_ids[] = $term_id;
                }
            }

            Log::info("Obtained the category IDs:", $cat_ids);
            return $cat_ids;

        }

        private function skipCategory($categoryName) {
            return $categoryName == 'Unused'
                || stripos($categoryName, "Height") !== false
                || stripos($categoryName, "H:") !== false
                || $categoryName == 'Yes';
        }

        private function attachTermsToProduct($product_id, $term_ids)
        {
            $connection = 'wordpress'; 

            $term_ids = array_filter($term_ids);

            foreach ($term_ids as $term_id) {
                $exists = DB::connection($connection)
                    ->table('term_relationships')
                    ->where('object_id', $product_id)
                    ->where('term_taxonomy_id', $term_id)
                    ->count();

                if (!$exists) {
                    DB::connection($connection)->table('term_relationships')->insert([
                        'object_id' => $product_id,
                        'term_taxonomy_id' => $term_id,
                        'term_order' => 0,  // This assumes you want the default order.
                    ]);
                }
            }

            foreach ($term_ids as $term_id) {
                $count = DB::connection($connection)
                    ->table('term_relationships')
                    ->where('term_taxonomy_id', $term_id)
                    ->count();

                DB::connection($connection)->table('term_taxonomy')
                    ->where('term_taxonomy_id', $term_id)
                    ->update(['count' => $count]);
            }
        }
```

The logs are outputting the correct IDs, I just can not see anything in WooCommerce.

```
[2023-08-05 08:36:30] local.INFO: Sections: {"Product Group":"Jewellery","Product Sub-Group 1":"Pendants","Product Type":"Gold"} 
[2023-08-05 08:36:30] local.INFO: Obtained the category IDs: ["486","490","488"] 
[2023-08-05 08:36:30] local.INFO: Section IDs:   
[2023-08-05 08:36:30] local.INFO: Array
(
    [0] => 486
    [1] => 490
    [2] => 488
)
```

Answer (score 1):

man I feel sorry for you having to handle the db connection like that. I would really attempt to abstract that. however anyways. given that you only listed functions $parent_id is not being set to anything in the beginning blocks...

```
// Insert into the term_taxonomy table
                    $connection->table('term_taxonomy')->insert([
                        'term_id' => $term_id,
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'parent' => $parent_id,
                    ]);
```